# Converting/expanding line into 2D polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I am brand new to GIS and am attempting to use QGIS to take an existing line from a shapefile and create a 2D polygon based on it i.e. I want to take a line and fatten it out a bit so it has an area.

Specifically I have a shapefile which represents centrelines of NZ rivers available from [NZ Land information data service](https://data.linz.govt.nz). I have managed to select the river segments that I want, and have merge them into one line (not sure about that step being useful) and saved as it's own shapefile which I can load into QGIS. For example the lines within the area circled in red in this image:[image: selection]

I would like to take this line (or each separate segment) and fatten it/them out into a 2D polygon area similar to the circled area in this image:[image: poly]

My 2D polygon would have branches though like the first image, and I would like to have one continuous polygon for the entire outline. (I would also like to calculate the area in hectares, but I believe this should be fairly trivial once I have the polygon)

What would be the best method to achieve this? Is there an feature/plugin in QGIS which can automatically fatten a line by specified amount? Is there a programmatic method I can use (I am fairly proficient at Python programming but not very familiar with QGIS)?

I am not expecting a one shot kill and do expect to do some manual drawing to achieve this but am hoping there is some technique or tool to help me out before I go ahead and manually draw the entire thing.

EDIT:

After seeing the answers posted I should clarify that I am trying to basically draw the outline of the "wet bed" of the rivers/creeks and is for my purposes arbitrary to a certain extent. So after consideration this would clearly not correspond to a set distance from the centre lines.

After seeing @UdithaGIS answer and looking at the topographic elevation data it appears what I need is more closely related to the contour lines (but not exactly). I will try to use the contours as a starting point and attempt to modify them for my needs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Apart from creating a buffer (as already proposed), you could also try to download OpenStreetMap data, as they often are already in polygon form. Simply creating an area around a line does not seem to make sense to me if you want to measure the area afterwards: this area will be completely arbitrary. So probably you should add some information what you need this for.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit @babel, you are correct that it doesn't make sense to create an area around the center lines, but for my purposes the area will be somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

[Single Symbol Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=symbology#single-symbol-renderer)

if you need to give a **width** to the line to represent the river width then you can `right click the layer > Properties > Symbology > select single symbol from the drop down > then change the width of the line ex- from 0.5 to 2`

and

[Categorized Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=symbology#categorized-renderer) or [Rule-based Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=symbology#rule-based-renderer)

if you need to make it pop up with main river with a higher width and other smaller tributaries smaller as they go up you have to number the rivers with **[Stream Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_order)** system and use the `Categorized` or `Rule Based` method instead of the `single symbol`. If you are intending to do analysis with a river network please represent the river as a line and give the width to the river with this method.

or

If you are trying to draw **watersheds** then you have to have a contour map or DEM or raster with elevation data like SRTM. then you will be able to drive more meaningful outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Create a buffer for your line layer (`Vector > Geoprocess tools > Buffer`) setting the width of the buffer in m. This creates a new polygon layer whose attributes you can modify with the `Fields calculator button` creating a new field with the function `$area` to calculate the area of each polygon.